# XAMPP - projects in htdocs cannot be accessed

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, xampp

I have many projects in my htdocs folder that don't use any PHP Framework
Since I installed Laravel (in an inner folder) I'm not able to access them from the browser, it always says:
"Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

I'm suspecting that the problem is the new .htaccess configurations that is inside of the Laravel project, but my question is how can I apply this configurations just in the inner-folder.

Comment: If you placed your `.htaccess` file on the root of localhost, that is `xampp/htdocs`, then you have to move it to the root of `Laravel`. I think it will solve the issue

Comment: The .htaccess file is located in the inner folder.

Comment: If so, then there is no chance for this error. Check whether you have any `.htaccess` on localhost root or you missing some of xampp files.

Comment: I found the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that I had this problem was because I added new virtual host, when I did that I overrided the automatic "localhost" one. so I had to manually add it to the code and now it's working.

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```